# PyCharm not Recognizing from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I am using Pycharm and although I am properly installed `pip install djangorestframework` I keeping getting an error as if it is not recognized:

[image]

I have tried several times but getting the same error and when I tried to install it from the Pycharm option when I hover over it I get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the virtual environment of your project in Pycharm interpreter settings